# Why does zsh kills my process every time I enter a git command

Tags: git, zsh, apple-m1

I'm trying to set up git on my apple M1 macbook air. I tried to run git and I saw that I needed to update my command-line-tools first and so did I. But now, every time I tried to enter a git command, I see the same line again and again: `zsh: killed     git`.

For example, when I type `git` the terminal tells me: `zsh: killed     git`, when I type `git --version` the terminal tells me: `zsh: killed     git --version` and so on. Does someone knows where the problem comes from and how to solve it?

Thanks for reading and trying to find an answer.

Comment: zsh is not killing your Git commands. zsh is reporting that someone else killed your Git commands. The someone else is no doubt the kernel: you're running an Intel-binary Git on an M1 without having prepared to do so, and the program doesn't work and the kernel kills it off in the process. You need to install an M1 version of the binaries, or set up Rosetta V2: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406686/is-every-program-that-ran-on-intel-macs-capable-of-being-run-on-the-new-m1-macs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here I put the final solution. I tried many methods on my mac M1, the best method is re-install homebrew.

Step1:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Step2:
Install homebrew

```
cd /opt 
mkdir homebrew # if not exist, just create one.
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Then, the problem solved.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but it fails even when I run mkdir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307622/receiving-zsh-killed-after-running-any-command-via-terminal-big-sur-m1-after

Comment: Didn't help with a similar Helm problem. I still have `zsh: killed     helm`

Comment: What actually helps is a comment on the question - you need to install arm64 version of the app.

Answer (score 7):

I used the below commands:

```
brew uninstall git
brew update
brew reinstall pcre2 gettext
brew install git
```

Git worked after.

Comment: In my case Github desktop was not working. Not sure if I reinstalled brew, but I reinstalled git using brew. Post which my problem was solved. Problem started post upgrading to macos Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 4):

To find out the cause of the crash, you can open `Console` with `⌘` + `spacebar`, then go to "Crash Reports".

If you scroll down a bit, you will find the source of the error:

> Application Specific Information:
> dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
> **/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib**

So in this example, a simple `brew reinstall gettext` will fix the issue (unless there is also an issue in another dependency of course).

To fix all dependencies issues in a single step, you could also simply do `brew reinstall $(brew deps git)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have an M1 with macOS Big Sur so I had to install the dev tools `xcode-select` first because reinstalling `gettext` or `pcre2` wasn't running either.

Did it in this order:

```
xcode-select --install
brew reinstall gettext
brew reinstall pcre2
brew reinstall git
```

Sheeeeesh!

Comment: Out of all the answers on top, only this worked :).. thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Fastlane Users

I was getting this error after installing rbenv and changing the ruby version I was using. Whenever I'd run bundle exec fastlane , zsh would immediately kill the process.

I fixed it by deleting the Gemfile.lock file and then running `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I have a MacBook Pro M1 and I run the next commands:

```
brew reinstall gettex
brew reinstall pcre2
brew reinstall git
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

```
brew reinstall $(brew deps git) git
```

or if it happens to some other software than git, replace with whatever is affected:

```
brew reinstall $(brew deps ffmpeg) ffmpeg
```

### Why?

It seems to occur after some important macOS update (it happened to me after the 12.2.1 update on Monterey). Some dependency was broken in the process.

Reinstalling only `git` is not enough. Reinstalling a specific dependency (`gettext` or `pcre2`) might work; all of them will. But if this happens to you with some other software, it might have many more deps: e.g., `ffmpeg` has 96. Automatically reinstalling all dependencies before reinstalling the sofware itself is the solution.

No need for the nuclear option of removing Homebrew and all its packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting xcode-select by

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this with running compiled go executables, after running `go build main.go` the main executable would be generated but zsh would kill it and rm the file when trying to run `./main.go`  Running `brew reinstall go` fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Before you reinstall anything, try re-cloning the repo.

I had this problem in only one repo and none of the other solutions here worked but re-cloning it fixed it for me.