# zsh killed git on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: git, macos

Run into an issue on MacOS Big Sur with Git. It returns `killed` and the problem is not fixed by reinstall the `git` using `brew reinstall git`

```
tp % git
zsh: killed     git
tp % bash
bash-3.2$ git
Killed: 9
```

Comment: Apple M1 + Homebrew? Seems like a popular problem recently: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20zsh%3a%20killed

Comment: Can you try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432398/7976758