# Gradle not working after installing from sdkman on mac

Tags: java, macos, gradle, sdkman

Hi I’m having an issue with my gradle installation on my Mac. I followed all the steps to get gradle 5.6.4 onto my machine using SDKMAN! I wanted to verify that I was actually installed by checking the version. The issue I’m having is that as soon as I send my request to check the version the mac’s terminal responds with **zsh: killed   gradle -v**. If someone could help me resolve this I would be truest grateful. I already have java 1.8 installed on my machine but and verified that it is actually there. So can someone help me out.

Comment: what's `headless 5.6.4`?  What's `the max terminal`?  So `java -version` works? what does `which gradle` show you?

Comment: Sorry about that @tim_yates. So headless was supposed to be gradle and max terminal was supposed to be mac’s terminal but it seems my phones autocorrect changed them sorry about that. When I run which gradle it shows me /Users/{userid}/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin/gradle

Comment: Hahaha, no worries  So just running `gradle --version` just crashes?

Comment: It sounds like this issue...  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3117 But that says it was fixed in version 5.3.  Can you try a more recent version of Gradle?

Comment: So I downloaded the latest version of gradle 6.8.3 and I’m still facing the same issue it instantly goes to that killed gradle -v message the second I run that command in terminal.

Comment: Did you upgrade your shell by chance? Try closing all Terminal windows and starting in a new one.

Comment: I closed all terminal windows and even restarted my computer just to see if that would work and I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Does this help find out why zsh is killing it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66637121/6509