# Receiving zsh: killed after running any command via terminal (Big Sur/M1) after OS updating

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

Receiving `killed` message after running any command via terminal
e.g.

```
$ ls
$ zsh: killed ls
```

some logs from Console

```
Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
--> 
    mapped file                 104929000-104931000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  Object_id=428ea44b

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 7, state_count: 4
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432398/3816741 - this answer doesn't help :(

Comment: The problem is fixing by system restart. Very often I've got the same issue after having run `pecl upgrade` that having try to update for example Redis extension...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution so decided to do a factory reset, it helped but not without other issues.

Faced with this one:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408876/m1-mac-clean-install-getting-stuck-at-create-a-computer-account

My advice, if you have a mac with M1 then be careful with reset and spend some time for researches, please.

Here is another one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkiX4qewq7U.

Finally, I've reset it, but it took me ages.