# zsh kills everytime I run pods for Xcode on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, apple-m1

I'm using pods to download the dependencies for Firebase Auth packages. But whenever I run $ pod init, I get - zsh killed  pods.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Cocoapods uses git heavily. So this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119081/why-does-zsh-kills-my-process-every-time-i-enter-a-git-command