# "clang --version" command not working in Mac terminal

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang, homebrew

I am trying to compile and run C programs on my 2019 MacBook Air Intel Core Ventura 13.4.1, with Visual Studio Code. For some reason, when I try to check if Clang is installed, with

```
clang --version
```

in my Terminal, it results in the following error:

```
zsh: killed clang --version
```

The same goes for when I installed GCC with Homebrew -- when I check for the version or try to compile something with clang or gcc, I get the kill command. Why is this happening?

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew and gcc, but the gcc commands still do not work. and neither does the clang command for compiling.

EDIT:
Not sure if this helps, but when I check for where gcc or clang is located with "which -a clang", it shows up twice in /usr/local/bin and once in /usr/bin

Comment: What does `type clang` show?

Comment: I think this is more a zsh shell problem than a C specific issue. That message is really unexpected. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119081/why-does-zsh-kills-my-process-every-time-i-enter-a-git-command).

Comment: Re "*I think this is more a zsh shell problem*", No. zsh is simply reporting that the program was killed with signal KILL.

Comment: @jules, Something on your system is sending the kill signal to those processes.

Comment: @Barmar "clang is /usr/local/bin/clang" is what is shown

Comment: @tadman I think I actually looked through that thread a few days, I uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew, but it still didn't fix the issue

Comment: I'll bet that `/usr/bin/clang --version` works. What does `file /usr/local/bin/clang` output? Are there any relevant messages in */private/var/log/system.log*? Since the SIGKILL is almost certainly being sent by the kernel there is a good chance the kernel also logged why it did so.

Comment: @KurtisRader '/usr/bin/clang --version' does work, and the output of file /usr/local/bin/clang gives this: /usr/local/bin/clang: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/local/bin/clang (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/local/bin/clang (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
output:               cannot open `output' (No such file or directory)